# Why can't i add an event from the week, day view in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, web2py

In my web2py application, i have used the fullcalendar plugin, to be able to add new events to my database. Now the problem comes when i go to my displayed calendar when i am in the month view, everything works perfectly, i can surely select a cell interval on the calendar and add an event using the ajax callback n the fullcalendar script, but when i switch view to week and day, i get a web2py ticket when i try to add an event by selecting an interval, like below;

```
<class 'ValueError'> invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'25T05:00:00'
```

Here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable:true,
                        header:{
                            left:'prev,next,today',
                            center:'title',
                            right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        height: "auto",
        contentHeight: "auto",
        events: [
        {{for i,row in enumerate(rows):}}{{if i!=0:}},{{pass}}
            {
                tip: '{{=row.id}}',
                title: '{{=row.title}}',
                allDay: false,
                start: new Date('{{=row.start_date}}'),
                end: new Date('{{=row.end_date}}')
            }
        {{pass}}
        ],
        selectable:true,
        selectHelper:true,
        droppable: true,
        eventRender: function(event, element,view) {
            if(event.start._d.getMonth() !== $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate')._d.getMonth()) {
              return false;
            }
            element.attr('title', event.title);
        },
            select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
                var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
                if(title){
                     var allDay = !start.hasTime() && !end.hasTime();
                 var start_date = moment(start).format();
                 var end_date = moment(end).format();
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "{{=URL('client','insert_event')}}",
                     type: "POST",
                     data:{ title:title,start:start_date,end:end_date},
                     success:function(data){
                         alert("Event Added!");
                         location.reload();
                     }
                 })
            }

        }
     });
});
```

and here is my controller function

```
def calendar():
rows = db(db.h_tasks).select()
return dict(rows=rows)
```

Comment: I don't know python (I found this via the fullCalendar tag) but it seems like maybe you're trying to allocate a date string (or part of one) to a variable which is supposed to be an integer? Where's the Python script you use to insert events? It seems like that's where the problem is. If it only occurs when you do it in the day/week views it'll be because the date now includes a time component, whereas in month view it just has a date. It seems like you may be naively splitting the string on the `-` character rather than trying to actually parse it as a date/time object?

Comment: Yes i had used the 'date' datatype that only takes a date but not the time and since the week and day views have time attached, the datatype date couldn't hundle, so i changed to datetime and everything wworks fine thank you for the eye opener, that was in my database defining

Comment: i had this `Field('start_date', 'date', requires=IS_DATE(format=T('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')), default=datetime.now()),`                                                       
 instead of this `Field('start_date', 'datetime', requires=IS_DATETIME(format=T('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')), default=datetime.now()),`